# error of installing numpy1.8.1 in win7 for python3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, windows-7

I need to install numpy 1.9.1 on win 7.

I have downloaded numpy-1.9.1.zip

from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/latest/download?source=files

I have installed python3.2.5.

But, in the install.txt file, i cannot find out how to install it.

I double clicked setup.py but MS DOS terminal window flashed and then disappeared immediately.

I also downloaded numpy‑MKL‑1.9.1.win32‑py3.2.exe from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy.

When I run the numpy-MKL-1.9.1.win32-py3.2.exe, I got:

```
 failed to start evelvated process (Shell Execute returned 2)
```

If I downloaded numpy-MKL-1.9.1.win-amd64-py3.2.exe and ran it, I got:

```
python version 3.2 required, which was not found in the registry.
```

After I added the registration key by following

```
http://codeyarns.com/2012/04/28/python-version-not-found-in-registry-error/
```

I got the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Just download the `.exe` from the website you linked, and run it. If you're using the python.org version of Python, it'll install automatically.

Comment: I have installed pytjon 3.2.5, I can run it from command line. Now I need to installed numpy. But, it is source file, no exe. I do not know how to install it. thanks

Comment: Do you have administrator access on your computer? Try right-clicking on the installer and running it as admin.

Comment: Based on your latest edit, you downloaded the Python 3.4 installer. Make sure you get the 3.2 version.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo.

Comment: Where did you install Python from? Is it from python.org, or is it another distribution like Enthought, Canopy, Anaconda, Portable Python, etc.?

Comment: I got it from python.org

Comment: Most of the packages of the scientific python stack do not support `python3.2` anymore. You may have to update to `>=python3.3` to get those packages working.